# How to use visualizationsForVaadin add-on?

Tags: gwt, widget, vaadin

I have a problem with the add-on for vaadin visualizationsForVaadin. I want to use the LineChart, but get the error on the page that it cannot finds the client compilation of the widgetset. I have successfully compiled the widgetset using maven. I have checked with firebug, that the widgetset is being loaded (there are no 404 or something like that), but still get this error. What am I doing wrong? Why cannot the page find the client compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have compiled the widgetset properly and it has included the addon?

Make sure that the loaded widgetset is the same that you just compiled. Check your web.xml and make sure you have the correct widgetset in the init-param with param-name `widgetset` (See MyWidgetset below).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <description>
            Vaadin application class to start</description>
            <param-name>application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
            <description>Application widgetset</description>
            <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
            <!-- <param-value>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet</param-value> -->
            <param-value>com.example.widgetset.MyWidgetset</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: It definitely is(at least the names are equal). I've just created another test project and compiled the widgetset from the eclipse plugin, deployed, and it works. In the another project, I am using maven2 plugin. Is there something different. Everything seems the same.

Comment: Can you please add pom.xml or at least the relevant parts of it to your original post?

Comment: I've made it work, however, still don't understand why. I have built the whole application (war package), compiled the widgetsets (maven gwt plugin) with maven and then copied the war package into jboss/standalone/deployments as I was used to from previous JBOSS versions (of course, the directory has changed). I could start the application although it couldn't find the widgetset. Then, I have deployed the war package in the JBOSS manager application and it worked. What is different there?